# Whitney's embedding theorem(s) and the existence of $C^\infty$ sub-atlas of a $C^k$ atlas

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In a lecture about differential geometry my teacher presented the following theorem:

**Theorem** (Whitney). Any $C^k$- atlas  $\mathcal{A}_{C^{k}}$ (with $k \geq 1$) of a topological manifold contains a $C^\infty$ - atlas.

However, when I searched for Whitney's theorems I only found his embedding theorems and no relation whatsoever to the theorem stated above. So here are my questions: How is the theorem above related to Whitney's embedding theorems? Are they equivalent?

Comment: Look for approximation theorems (e.g., in Hirsch's *Differential Topology*). Or google Whitney approximation.

Comment: Whitney is one of the founder of differential topology and he proved a lot more than the embedding theorem. I found a stronger statement (switching $C^\infty$ to analytic) in his paper in 1936 ([here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968482?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), p.654)